# Byteball vs. IOTA

Tags: iota-network

Can anyone explain how Byteball is implementing the directed acyclic graph (DAG) technology differently than IOTA? From their website, byteball.org, it appears that Byteball will be used more for human interactions, whereas we all know IOTA will be used for machine to machine transactions. I am just curious if anyone else has looked into this.

Comment: Can you focus on some area where you want the two compared? Otherwise this is asking for quite a big analysis.

Comment: Apologies. I just found a very useful thread on Reddit that answered my questions: https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/6l06su/iota_vs_byteball/?utm_source=reddit-android. And you are correct, it is quite an analysis. Two completely different animals.